# If each strict subgroup of G is free, must G be free or cyclic of prime order ?

Tags: gr.group-theory

If each strict subgroup of a group G is free, must G be free or cyclic of prime order ?

Comment: What's a strict subgroup?

Comment: I think, strict=proper. Then there are even finitely-generated groups  $G$ where every proper subgroup is infinite cyclic, but $G$ is not virtually free (Olshansky's central extensions of Tarsky monsters). However, if you add the condition that $G$ contains a free nonabelian subgroup, I do not think there are any know counter-examples. 

Comment: Search on Google "almost free groups" 


Comment: It's a well known open question whether there's a non-free word-hyperbolic group with every proper subgroup free.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No. There is a variation of Tarski monster: a nonabelian group whose each proper nontrivial subgroup is infinite cyclic, see [the book of Olshanskii](http://books.google.ru/books?hl=en&lr=&id=jwNkqFQn-GcC&oi=fnd&pg=PR5&dq=olshanskii+geometry+of+defining&ots=XQQkt5vng4&sig=jNhR97XokHHkZU_qaDboCH6EbDc&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Concerning Misha's comment. For any countable family of countable involution-free groups $G_1,G_2,\dots$, there is a group $H$ containing all $G_i$ as proper subgroups such that each proper subgroup of $H$ is either infinite cyclic or a conjugate of a subgroup of some $G_i$. This is [Obraztsov's embedding theorem](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=sm&paperid=2990&option_lang=eng).

Comment: Very nice, Anton, I forgot about Obraztsov's theorem!

Comment: Thanks. I thought this had already been answered, but I had no keyword.